# Squier Stratocaster's Bridge Lift After Restringing with Ernie Ball Beefy Slinkies

Tags: tuning, bridge, stratocaster

Squier Strat, my high E string snapped yesterday, so I replaced all strings.

I used Ernie Ball's Beefy Slinky (2627) with following gauge numbers:

1. E (11)
2. B (15)
3. G (22p)
4. D (30)
5. A (42)
6. E (54)

When tuning, I found a LOT of resistance from the strings when tuning to standard EADGBE. My gut told me that something's off, and I saw the bridge lifting up all the way. Immediately relaxed pressure by loosening the strings, to not damage it.

My guess: I used the incorrect gauge (Guy at guitar center suggested 2627 Beefy Slinky). Please do offer your suggestions.

Comment: From Sweetwater: "These strings are perfect for those who love to detune their guitars." From a Google review: "These strings are super for their designed purpose. Low tuning. I used them on a Lap Steel Guitar in Low Open G; DGDGBE"

Comment: Store should have a micrometer. Take your old strings in & get them measured, assuming you want something similar. I use fat strings… but they're FAT.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the old strings were a lot lighter in gauge. The compensating *springs* connecting the underside of the mechanism will need tightening (or even adding to) to compensate for the extra tension the new strings exert.

In fact, unless you want beefy strings, which will be more difficult to bend, but give you a fatter sound, go for a lighter gauge set anyway. The neck, thus action, will also probably need some tweaking to compensate too - trussrod most likely.

Not knowing what was already on, it's impossible to give any more than these vague instructions. But for me, they're too heavy for standard Strat playing.

Comment: I expect adjusting the springs would fix this up. I have used routinely "heavy lights" on a strat which are not all that different. I currently have the tremolo blocked, but prior to that I the spring tension was sufficient. Easy enough to adjust considering the OP prob has the back off to change the strings anyway. I don't use drop tuning

Comment: @Yorik - didn't consider it necessary to take the back plate off to change strings!

Comment: on a strat, the alignment of the slot (in the cover plate) with the string holes (in the tremolo mechanism) can be offset depending on the string tension.